# MS Access 2003 Company Report

Tags: mysql, sql, report, ms-access-2003

I'm running MS Access 2003, and I am not that familiar with it. The database tracks billing for companies and their line of business. Company ID's are matched with LoB ID's. On a report, for example, the company might be GAP and LineofBusiness may be Shirts, or something, so GAP SHIRTS. Well, say I wanted GAP SHIRTS and GAP PANTS to turn up on an "Agency" report, but I wanted to use GAP SANDALS for just a "GAP" report .. Is it even possible? There are other reports that use this information, so I can't really change anything in the Tables for each. Note, there are other companies and subsidiaries that are in the 2 tables also.

Basically, for some LoB (Shirts/Pants), I want them to be grouped in an Agency report under the company XYZ (who they are connected to in the table/db), but Sandals LoB to be reported under GAP. How do I identify the differences in reporting the groups? I attached a screen shot of what it looks like so far.

It will print out the report correct for all the other companies except for 2. I need "XYZ" and "GAP" along with only a select few of LoB's to print out on one report titled "Agency". Keep in mind that the LoB's are indeed all connected to their corresponding companies, however for accounting purposes we need this change implemented.

Also, I am no where near an expert at writing queries or even establishing one.

I hope I was clear enough.

Thanks.

Below is a screen shot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTRms.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[table].[CompanyID] & "-" & [table].[LoBID]

http://www.techonthenet.com/access/queries/concatenate.php

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am new to concatenate. I will do more research.